# Quantum simulation of molecular spectroscopy: why?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-computer, molecular-dynamics, quantum-chemistry

Molecular spectroscopy, e.g. through light-matter interaction, is a powerful tool to measure molecular properties such as bond lengths, energy levels, vibration frequencies, ... which give insights about the molecule's structure.

The simulation of molecular spectra can be challenging on classical computers, as it requires to solve an intrinsically quantum problem. One has to compute wavefunctions, estimate their overlaps (Frank-Condon factors), etc. All this are hard problems, whose complexity can be related to the one of boson sampling.

However, ideas have been proposed and implemented in proof of principle experiments, to simulate spectra of small molecules on quantum simulators. The idea is based on performing beam-splitter, squeezing and displacement transformations (Doktorov transformation) on a number of bosonic modes, to then measuring the resulting state. Typically, the parameters for this transformations are obtained from an harmonic approximation of the potential energy surfaces (PES), that are computed numerically under some approximations (Born–Oppenheimer).

What I'm missing is, what do we really learn from these simulated spectra? What can they be useful for? Is it the point that one can look at transition that e.g. would require unavailable lasers or measurement precision? Or what else?

One of my main point of confusion is that they are based on computed PES, and approximations. So can they really give any insight on the real physical system? And if yes, why are these impossible to obtain from the real system itself?

Comment: Some spectra contain states that are useful for metrology, e.g. thorium oxide has an electron electric dipole moment-sensitive state. Ab initio calculations are useful to find these states and estimate how sensitive they are to the quantity in question.

Comment: Are you asking why simulations of spectra are useful in general, or are you asking why the method in the third paragraph is useful/different to existing methods?

Comment: Also, sometimes only broad features of a spectrum are known. E.g. nitrogen vacancy- centers in diamond have a singlet manifold through which states in the excited triplet decay, but the precise pathway is not understood.

Comment: @HansWurst you are right, the simulation method is not the crucial point here. I often encounter this simulation idea in the context of quantum computers, so I was trying to understand why it is so interesting to simulate (roto-vibrational) spectra.

Comment: Many experiments are not as clear cut as you might think. Having a simulation typically helps to identify and to ascertain the results. Imagine you have some sort of process that can lead to a large selection transient species that cannot be isolated, but you are able to measure a spectrum. In this case you can verify your assumption about the transient species by doing calculations on all the possible options and then identify it by matching it with the experiment. This is one example of a application of simulation of spectra. There are many more but the question is too broad in my opinion.